# Three js collada animation set time

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

Is there a way to set time or keyframe in collada animation keyframes ?

Im trying to, but i got unexpected behaviour.

```
function playAt(a){


    for (var i = 0; i < kfAnimationsLength; ++i) {
        kfAnimations[i].pause();
        kfAnimations[i].play(false, a);
        kfAnimations[i].update(0);
    } 
}
```

I searched all day long, but still dont found any solution to do it.

Any idea  ?

Answer (score 0):

got it :

```
function playAt(a){


    for (var i = 0; i < kfAnimationsLength; ++i) {
        kfAnimations[i].stop();
        kfAnimations[i].play(false, a);
        kfAnimations[i].update(a);

    }

}
```

But still got some unexpected behaviour, i imported my camera from collada.
And she seem not to support update like this